# Generate regular expression for ng-pattern in Angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In Angular 1.2 it was possible to use ng-pattern as follows:

```
<input ng-model="myModelVar" ng-pattern="myModelRegex" />
```

where myModelRegex could be something like: `/^[a]+$/i` for a case insensitive match on a number of `a`'s. Since AngularJS 1.5 the behaviour has changed (as shown in their documentation: [see here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#forms-inputs-and-ngmodel)).

What I want to achieve is something like:

```
  $scope.testRegex = '^[a]+$';

  $scope.generateRegex = function(modelVar) {
    return new RegExp(modelVar, 'i');
  }
```

with:

```
  <input ng-pattern="generateRegex(testRegex)" name="testInput3" ng-model="testVar3" />
```

So, my regex is actually a model variable, and is supplied by an external source. It doesn't matter that people can change it, the backend filters this as well.

The example above "works", but  throws an `infDigest` error. See my jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/t0nfurjb/

What do I need to do to fix this?

[EDIT]

So, to clarify, I do a web call, which returns me something like this:

```
[
{
 caption: "Please enter your mail address";
 regex: [a-z]+@[a-z]+.[a-z]+
},
{
 caption: "Please enter your phone number";
 regex: [0-9]{10}
}
]
```

And I want to use the provided regexes in my view.

*Note: the regexes are made up on the spot and should never ever ever ever be used in actual systems.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out!

```js
angular
  .module('demoApp', [])
  .controller('MainController', MainController)

function MainController($scope) {
  var modelVariable;
  $scope.testVar = 'bb';
  getRegex();
  $scope.regex = new RegExp(modelVariable, 'i');
  
  function getRegex() {
    // get regex via data source and set it on local variable.
    modelVariable = '^[b]+$';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="MainController">

  <form name="testForm">
    <!-- What I want: -->
    <input ng-pattern="regex" name="testInput" ng-model="testVar" />
    <input type="submit" />
    <pre>
    input: {{testVar}}
    $error: {{testForm.testInput.$error}}
    </pre>
    <br />

  </form>
  <pre>

</pre>
</div>
```

This works too as well [jsfiddle e.g. Angular 1.4.8](https://jsfiddle.net/78rfrsb2/1/) and is much simpler compared to the above one, [the same e.g. in plnkr with Angular 1.5.5](https://plnkr.co/edit/YohuBjP6587aklfA4ynX?p=preview)

UPDATE:

Simple example using ng-repeat directive and ng-form directive.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
    .margin-bottom {
      margin-bottom: 2%;
    }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <form role="form" name="heroForm" novalidate="novalidate">
      <div class="margin-bottom" ng-repeat="hero in ctrl.heroes">
        <ng-form name="heroFieldForm">
          <label>{{hero.name}}</label>
          <div>
            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="hero.email" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="ctrl.getRegex('email')"/>
            <span ng-show="heroFieldForm.email.$invalid">Valid Email Required</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <label>Phone:</label>
            <input type="tel" name="phone" ng-model="hero.phone" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="ctrl.getRegex('phone')"/>
            <span ng-show="heroFieldForm.phone.$invalid">Valid Phone Required</span>
          </div>
        </ng-form>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>

angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);

function DefaultController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.heroes = heroes;
  vm.regexes = regexes;
  vm.getRegex = getRegex;

  function getRegex(type) {
    if (type === 'email') {
      return vm.regexes[0].regex;
    } else {
      return vm.regexes[1].regex;
    }
  }
}

var heroes = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Batman',
    email: 'unknown',
    phone: 'unknown'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Alfred Pennyworth',
    email: 'alfred@waynemanor.com',
    phone: '9988776655'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Robin',
    email: 'robin@wayneinc.com',
    phone: 'unknown'
  }
  ];

var regexes = [
  {
    caption: "Please enter your mail address",
    regex: '^[a-z]+@[a-z]+.[a-z]+$'
  },
  {
    caption: "Please enter your phone number",
    regex: '^[0-9]{10}$'
  }
  ];
```

[The plnkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/3sNLVD8dY0fEp1cXznaK?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately this won't work for my scenario, because it is actually used in an ng-repeat. So, I can't just use a global variable.

Comment: Do all the items in the ng-repeat template follow the same validation pattern by using ng-pattern directive? If all items will have the same validation pattern then using a common variable is better than storing each pattern into its own model item in the array.

Comment: No, it's a per item thing.

Comment: Have you tried ng-form directive, you can have a regex for each item in the array on the $scope check this https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-dynamic-angular-forms-with-ngrepeat-and-ngform

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to allow custom regexes?

Comment: Do you get the regex as a property in the actual data, how are you mapping the regex to the particular item?. AFAIK ng-form will help you with validating each item by giving a name in the ng-form directive and using it as item1Form.input1.$pattern whereas usage of the ng-pattern directive remains the same (but on an element i.e. inside an ng-repeat) as I pointed out in this answer.

Comment: I've edited the question to show the origin of my data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116471/discussion-between-abdul-mateen-mohammed-and-yuri).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put it into ng-pattern attribute without creating function if your regex variable is scope variable:
`<input ng-pattern="{{testRegex}}" name="testInput3" ng-model="testVar3" />`

Comment: This won't work for me, the regex is supplied by backend. I get a list of items with regexes, so I need to load them via an ngRepeat.